# ValueError: The slave is indicating an error. The response is: '\x01\x83\x02\xc0\xf1' minimalmodbus

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am new to Modbus protocol and I am using minimalmodbus python package to get data from Modbus RTU slave.The slave is [L&T Quasar Module](http://www.larsentoubro.com/electrical-automation/products-services/products/meters/energy-management-products/quasar-multi-parameter-panel-meter/). Python Code is as below :

```
import minimalmodbus
import serial
import sys
instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0', 1)
instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0', 1,mode='rtu')
instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU   # rtu or ascii mode
instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600   # Baud
instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
instrument.serial.parity   = serial.PARITY_EVEN
instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
instrument.serial.timeout  = 0.05   # seconds
print instrument.read_register(30001, 2) #register address, number of registers
```

The output is:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "Desktop/meter/minimal_test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print instrument.read_register(30001, 2) #register address, number of registers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/minimalmodbus-0.7-py2.7.egg/minimalmodbus.py", line 258, in read_register
    return self._genericCommand(functioncode, registeraddress, numberOfDecimals=numberOfDecimals, signed=signed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/minimalmodbus-0.7-py2.7.egg/minimalmodbus.py", line 697, in _genericCommand
    payloadFromSlave = self._performCommand(functioncode, payloadToSlave)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/minimalmodbus-0.7-py2.7.egg/minimalmodbus.py", line 798, in _performCommand
    payloadFromSlave = _extractPayload(response, self.address, self.mode, functioncode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/minimalmodbus-0.7-py2.7.egg/minimalmodbus.py", line 1088, in _extractPayload
    raise ValueError('The slave is indicating an error. The response is: {!r}'.format(response))
```

ValueError: The slave is indicating an error. The response is: '\x01\x83\x02\xc0\xf1'*

The slave responded as expected using MODSCAN on a windows machine.